# How to upgrade from free to commercial without losing user data

Tags: android

I'm developing an App that is distributed in two versions: free with ads and payed with no ads. A part from the presence of ads, the apps are completely identical.

Generally users are thought to get the free version and then - if they like - upgrade to the commercial version.

When I upload the app to google play, I must create a completely new app, with a new unique id. In other words, these two versions of the same app are actually two completely different projects, and, as I see, there's no way to avoid this.

This makes sense, as soon as I have to monitor which app provides me which income.

BUT - now comes the problem - when a user decides to upgrade from the free to the commercial version, I would like him to keep all his local data. Obviously this does not happen, as soon as the two applications have different name.

Is there an easy solution for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Add an import export option, use a content provider or use shared user IDs (not recommended)

Comment: Can you explain better the second and third options please?

Comment: [Shared User IDs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) and [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: What if you use the same project for both by adding a fragment or widget with ads in the activities? Then, if the user has paid, you just hide the ads.

Comment: Yes nachodeh, but how do you understand if the user has paid, if the project is unique? And how integrate the google play payment service if you have only one project? This function could be used if you integrate some sort of in-app payment only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to share data between free and paid apps when the user upgrades from the the free to the paid version

This is a very common problem fraught with all sorts of issues, including the following:

- When the user installs *AND RUNS* the paid app, all user data should be
  copied from the free app.
- If the user tries to use the free app after he has completed the
  upgrade to paid, he should be automatically redirected to the paid
  app.
- When the user deletes the paid app, then the free app should be permitted to continue working as previously.

The easiest solution is to maintain all data that must be shared in a database instead of user preferences. Then, the database file can be literally copied from the free to the paid application when the paid app is run for the first time.

I have found this to work better than Content Providers for me because of all the special use case conditions regarding only one or the other or both apps being installed at any one time.

In order for this system to work, several key tools have to be in place:

- The apps have to be able to detect if each other are installed at
  runtime.
- The apps have to know where their counterparts save their database
  file.
- Several flags have to be saved in the database file to indicate what
  has happened.

**How to determine if the other app is installed**:

```
final String packageName = "com.company.other-app-name";
android.content.pm.PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
```

If `info==null` or a `NameNotFoundException` is thrown, then the app is not installed.

**How to copy the database file**:

Your database files are stored like this:

```
paidDb = "/data/data/<paid-app-package-name>/databases/<db-name>.db"
freeDb = "/data/data/<free-app-package-name>/databases/<db-name>.db"
```

Your copy function should open `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` objects on these files and copy them by any number of standard methods such as this:

```
while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
```

This should provide all the tools you need in order to allow the paid app to determine if the free app is installed, and if it is installed copy the database and continue from there. The free app should check to see if the paid app is installed. If so, either quit with a friendly warning or redirect to the paid app, like this:

```
android.content.pm.PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
startActivity( intent );
finish();
```

**Optional Delete the Free App**:

After the paid app detects the free app and copies the database, you can optionally ask the user to delete the free app, like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("package:<free-app-package-name>");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_UNINSTALL_FREE_APP);
```

Note: You cannot guarantee that the user will actually uninstall the free app as requested. The value `REQUEST_CODE_UNINSTALL_FREE_APP` is used so that when you return from the uninstaller in `onActivityResult()` of the paid app, you can check to see if the user completed the delete. Then, if the uninstall didn't happen you can provide the usual 'Are you sure?' or 'Try again?' dialogs or even get all draconian on him (*not recommended*) and force him to finish the uninstall before allowing him to continue using the new paid app.

**Further Consideration**:

- All of your shared code should be in an [Android LIbrary Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) and
  each of the apps should be lightweight wrapper projects using the
  shared library. All three projects will be in a single Eclipse
  workspace.
- Consider using [Android License Verification Library (LVL)](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html) for
  the paid app project (you will not need LVL for the Library Project
  or for the free app).
- Also consider scrapping all of these ideas, making just one single
  application, and using [In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html) to upgrade from free to paid.
  This is way beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Very clear, thanks! Although converting everything to a db now, I think it looks difficult. I'll keep it in mind for the next project, when I'll start the user data management from scratch.